# Wordpress change permalinks and redirect new urls 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I was using this WordPress permalink string.

```
/%postname%-%post_id%.html
```

but now I want to change it to, and redirect all old url's to new url's

```
/%postname%.html
```

Sample old url is;

```
http://www.example.com/dead-trigger-2-hile-mod-apk-indir-1890.html
```

The new url will be;

```
http://www.example.com/dead-trigger-2-hile-mod-apk-indir.html
```

My htaccess file currently using default wordpress vars. How can redirect all my urls to new urls 301.

I tryed to use this, but its not working

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)-([0-9]{4})$ http://www.example.com/$1
```

Comment: So you want to omit post id from URL?

Comment: Yes exactly at wordpress and redirect with htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)-(\d+)/$ http://example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

By following code you will be able to achieve 301 redirect via .Htaccess :

**Syntax :**

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.html http://www.yoursite.com/newpage.html
```

**Example :**

```
  # BEGIN 301 Redirects
    Redirect 301 /dead-trigger-2-hile-mod-apk-indir-1890.html http://www.example.com/dead-trigger-2-hile-mod-apk-indir.html
  # END 301 Redirects
```

Comment: Dude i want to redirect all urls. All posts url address. I know how to write 301 rewrite url this way.